# I have two json docs, I need to compare if the keys from the first object, exists in the second object using python. Both of them are nested

Tags: python, json

I want to compare the keys of these two json documents, that have nested keys in them not depending on their order. So the success criteria for both of them will be, if the definitions json object contains all of the keys from the content json object.

**Content JSON:**

```
{
    "content": {
      "item": {
        "itemNo": "332972",
        "itemType": "COM",
        "description": "xxx"
      }
    }
```

**Definitions JSON:**

```
"definitions": {
      "Item": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "itemNo",
          "itemType"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "itemNo": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "332972",
            "description": "Unique identifier for an Item"
          },
          "itemType": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "COM",
            "description": "Defines the type of Item"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "xxx"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I expect **true/success** output for the following two json objects because all of the keys are present in the definitions json

I tried the following code:

```
  for i in d.keys():
      array.append(i)
      for j in d[i].keys():
          array.append(j)
          wrapper = array
  return wrapper
```

But I am getting only results from the first nest

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Load them both with `json.loads()`, then for each key in the content dict, check if that key is also present in the definitions dict.  What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I tried doing a loop between them, but it returns me only the first nest of the object. Example:  `for i in d.keys():
                    array.append(i)
                    for j in d[i].keys():
                        array.append(j)
                        wrapper = array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with implementing 2 functions.

First one for getting all the keys from definitions

```
def get_keys(dl, keys_list):
                    if isinstance(dl, dict):
                        keys_list += dl.keys()
                        map(lambda x: get_keys(x, keys_list), dl.values())
                    elif isinstance(dl, list):
                        map(lambda x: get_keys(x, keys_list), dl)
                keys_list = []
                get_keys(definitions, keys_list)
```

and then implementing second function that will go through the above list (reusing from @Green Cloak Guy):

```
  def verify_keys(content, definitions):
                    for k,v in content.items():
                        if k not in keys_list:
                            return False
                        if type(v) == dict and type(definitions[k]) == dict:
                            if not verify_keys(v, definitions[k]):
                                return False
                    return True

                verify_keys(content, definitions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template for a simple recursive function that checks whether each key in `content` exists at the corresponding level in `definitions`. It's probably not specific enough for your particular needs, but should be fairly easy to modify.

```
def verify_keys(content, definitions):
    for k,v in content.items():
        if k not in definitions:  # check key in this level
            return False
        if type(v) == dict and type(definitions[k]) == dict:
            if not verify_keys(v, definitions[k]):  # check recursively
                return False
    return True

...
with open('content.json', 'r') as content_file, open('definitions.json', 'r') as defs_file:
    content = json.loads(content_file.read())
    definitions = json.loads(defs_file.read())

print(verify_keys(content, definitions)
```

Comment: yes, this does the trick if both of the json structures has the same depth. But not if for example the definitions json has most of the keys I need located in properties. So this will return false always, because it is not checking the whole definitions doc but checking only on first level depth.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is less dynamic then the other solution but faster if the schema you provided is what you are actually doing.

Assuming `content` is the first `dict` you gave and `definitions` is the second.

```
cont_dict = content['content']['item']
def_dict = definitions['definitions']['Item']['properties']

result = True if set(cont_dict.keys()).issubset(def_dict.keys()) else False
print(result)
```

This can be one lined but for readability purposes I made it several.

Comment: This will work for this particular json only, I want to make it dynamically so I put any json to be compared as needed.

Comment: Yeah I figured thats why I added the disclaimer at the top. If it was static format then this would be faster. If you need dynamic then the other option is better.